# remove object from array in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

How can i remove a candid from the below array collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58978989"),
    "positionId" : "54535343",
    "jobTitle" : "Developer",
    "status" : "Open",
    "jobDescription" : "HyperLink Place holder",
    "candidate" : [ 
        {
            "candid" : ObjectId("b20474567892345678900021")
        }, 
        {
            "candid" : ObjectId("b30474567892345678900021")
        }, 
        {
            "candid" : ObjectId("b40474567892345678900021")
        }, 
        {
            "candid" : ObjectId("b50474567892345678900021")
        }
    ]
}
```

expected output is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58978989"),
    "positionId" : "54535343",
    "jobTitle" : "Developer",
    "status" : "Open",
    "jobDescription" : "HyperLink Place holder",
    "candidate" : [ 
        {
            "candid" : ObjectId("b20474567892345678900021")
        }, 
        {
            "candid" : ObjectId("b30474567892345678900021")
        }, 
        {
            "candid" : ObjectId("b40474567892345678900021")
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the array contains identical objects I assume you want to delete a specific index. If so then use the following.

```
db.test.update({_id: ObjectId("58978989")}, {$unset: {"candidate.1": 1}})
db.test.update( { _id: ObjectId("58978989")}, { $pull: { candidate: null} } )
```

Have a look at this to learn more
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: This is will result in the document you wanted. If this is not helping you please provide more info so we can help you.

Comment: the above query is working fine in robomongo but when i was trying to run the same query using model in my node app it is not running